# Remove prefix from all data in a single column in R

Tags: r, prefix

I would have a column where the data looks like this:

```
M999-00001
M999-00002
...
```

Is there a way to remove all the 'M's in the column in R?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Try to post [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) next time. Take a look at `substr`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
df1[,1] <- sub("^.", "", df1[,1])
```

Or use `substring`

```
substring(df1[,1],2)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col1 = c("M999-00001", "M999-0000"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use gsub function for the same

```
Col1 <- gsub("[A-z]","",Col1)
[1] "999-00001" "999-0000"
```

## data

```
Col1 = c("M999-00001", "M999-0000")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>%
transform(col_name=str_replace(col_name,"M",""))
```

Use it only if you have installed `stringr` library and `magrittr` library